# How to make the div inside wrapper bigger than wrapper itself without change the structure

Tags: html, css

How to make the `<div>` inside wrapper bigger than wrapper itself without change the structure?

**HTML**

```
<div class="page row1">
    <div class="home-wrapper row2">
        <div class="home-slider row3"></div>
    </div>
<div>
```

**CSS**

```
.page { width: 100%; height: 400px; border: 1px solid #000; background: #eee; }
.home-wrapper { width: 90%; height: 400px;border: 1px solid red; background: #ccc; margin: 0 auto;}
.home-slider{ width: 100%; height: 200px; border: 1px solid blue; background:#000; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/46vpqmgh/1/

I want the black box is same width with the page `<div>` without change the structure, using only CSS.

Thanks

Comment: i need to fit the width, not height but @ling-s

Answer (score 1):

Add:

- `position: absolute` to `.home-slider` to pull it out of the normal flow
- `top: 0` and `left: 0` to `.home-slider` to position it correctly
- `position: relative` to `.page` to make it's children absolute positioned elements relative to it

Percentage height and width will be calculated based on the size of `.page`.

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/xmzvs6xa/)

Added CSS

```
.page {
    position: relative;
}
.home-slider {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

[Read more about the CSS position property over on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> Absolute positioning
>
> Elements that are positioned relatively are still considered to be in the normal flow of elements in the document. In contrast, an element that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes up no space when placing other elements. **The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor**. If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, the initial container is used.

In our example above, the nearest positioned "ancestor" is `.page`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following properties. [Looks](http://jsfiddle.net/46vpqmgh/6/) fair to me.

```
.home-slider {
    /* ... */
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: -5%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: `position: fixed` makes it positioned relative to the viewport which works fine in this example but would be a pain with other elements on the page.

Comment: you're right, upvoted your answer already. i thought of it as a quick fix though, don't hit me :)

Comment: \* lowers hand \* raised @Seçkin.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following class:

```
.home-slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background:#000;
    position: absolute;/*Add position absolute*/
    left: 0;/*Add left to 0*/
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/46vpqmgh/7/)